# How to initialize static std::array with static const variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray

How to initialize static std:array that uses static const variable as size? I tried searching for similar questions but `std::array` is relatively new so theres not much to be found.

```
// ExampleClass.h
class ExampleClass {
    public:
        static const size_t NUMBER_OF_INDEXES = 5;
    private:
        static std::array<int, NUMBER_OF_INDEXES> myArray;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like any other static data member, `ExampleClass::myArray` should have an out-of-line definition in exactly one translation unit, where you write down its type and its qualified name as usual:

```
std::array<int, ExampleClass::NUMBER_OF_INDEXES> ExampleClass::myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```